# iOS - AFNetworking - How to return the responseObject inside the block

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I have to make two API call with AFNetworking, but the problem is that I need to wait the result before to go further...

I use Google API Places to get the detail of a place thanks to the reference. 
I have a Place FROM and a place TO ... So I make two call...

The problem is that after that I call my function to get the detail, the execution is going further... I'm not very familiar with blocks. If I understood, it will execute the code in another thread...

The function where I need to get details of FROM and TO :

```
- (IBAction)getDetailsTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableDictionary *googleDetail;
    // Looking for detail for FROM
    googleDetail= [googleAPICaller searchGooglePlaceDetail:[self.from valueForKey:@"reference"]];
    [self.from setValue:[googleDetail valueForKey:@"result"][@"geometry"][@"location"][@"lat"] forKey:@"lat"];
    [self.from setValue:[googleDetail valueForKey:@"result"][@"geometry"][@"location"][@"lng"] forKey:@"lng"];

    // Looking for detail for TO
    googleDetail = [googleAPICaller searchGooglePlaceDetail:[self.destination valueForKey:@"reference"]];
    [self.destination setValue:[googleDetail valueForKey:@"result"][@"geometry"][@"location"][@"lat"] forKey:@"lat"];
    [self.destination setValue:[googleDetail valueForKey:@"result"][@"geometry"][@"location"][@"lng"] forKey:@"lng"];

    [accessibilityAPICaller searchJourney:self.from to:self.destination];
}
```

My function to get the detail of place :

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)searchGooglePlaceDetail:(NSString *)reference
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", reference, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    __block NSMutableDictionary *result;
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        result = responseObject;
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation waitUntilFinished];
    return result;
}
```

I would like to be sure that the execution of `searchGooglePlaceDetail` is completely done before to go further.
It seems that `searchJourney` is called before that I was able to make the previous instructions...
After my research in internet, I found `[operation waitUntilFinished];` I tried it, but it looks like that the execution keeps going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a delegate protocol in your `accessibilityAPICaller` class, and then make sure your view controller implements that delegate and being set as the delegate itself.

Then you can implement methods like `didReceiveJourney:` in your view controller, and call that when you've received the data.

If you haven't implemented a delegate protocol before, [here's Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) about it.

Comment: I did create a delegate protocol to resolve my issue. Btw, I need the protocol for the getDetailGooglePlace, not for the journey :) .
But thanks for the help. Technically, this solution resolved the problem.

Comment: Cool, the protocol can be anything you want. Just make sure you also implement protocol on when the web service call fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the second call inside the block completion block of the first call:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)searchGooglePlaceDetail:(NSString *)reference
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", reference, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    __block NSMutableDictionary *result;
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1 = [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        result = responseObject;
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        googleDetail = [googleAPICaller searchGooglePlaceDetail:[self.destination valueForKey:@"reference"]];
        [self.destination setValue:[googleDetail valueForKey:@"result"][@"geometry"][@"location"][@"lat"] forKey:@"lat"];
        [self.destination setValue:[googleDetail valueForKey:@"result"][@"geometry"][@"location"][@"lng"] forKey:@"lng"];

        [accessibilityAPICaller searchJourney:self.from to:self.destination];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
    return result;
}
```

In the case of AFNetworking, blocks are used much like a callback in javascript. It is the piece of code that executes after the call has returned.

You have two blocks which may or may not execute. A success block if the request was successful and a failure block if the request has failed.

Comment: Is it really the only one solution ? 
Because I want to update my `getDetailsTapped`.
I will put condition to check if the `FROM` or the `TO` is the location of the user... If it's the location of the user, I don't need to make a request to google API. I just need to get the location thanks to `CLLocationManager`. That's why I prefer to separate well those executions... :/

Comment: well you will have to do at least one call, so do the check in the completion block. If it is satisfied, don't do the next call

Answer (score -1):

```
    You can use this block to get google places and above request also work with this block 

-(void) getGoogleData {            

        // 1

              NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=50000&types=%@&sensor=false&key=%@",<latitude>,<longitude>,type,GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY];

            NSLog(@"Url string:%@",string);

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            // 2
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
            operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                // 3
                NSDictionary *googleData= (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
                NSLog(@"googleData:%@",[googleData JSONRepresentation]);


            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                // 4
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];
            }];

            // 5
            [operation start];


        }
```